MYSQL Explode String in PHP
I have a string in a column (INFO) as below. I want to populate the information into PHP that makes it more readable.
{"name":"Trevor Ackermann","company":"","address":"","post_code":"","city":"","country":"","phone1":"","phone2":"","email":""}

So what I need to do is Echo the name segment on it's own same with all the other segments in PHP page
SQL Query and SQL Select shows me only all the information in the column

Why not decode in PHP side?

@Justinas yes that is what I meant

So do echo json_decode($row['column_name'], true)['name']?

The best solution would be to normalise the data structure and create a table with the json keys being the column names. Next time, please tag your question correctly. If you want to perform this operation in php, then the question should have been tagged with php only.

How to extract and access data from JSON with PHP?
